# python convert "unicode" as list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a doubt about treat a return type in python.

I have a database function that returns this as value:

```
(1,13616,,"My string, that can have comma",170.90)
```

I put this into a variable and did test the type:

```
print(type(var))
```

I got the result:

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

I want to convert this to a list and get the values separeteds by comma.

Ex.:

```
var[0] = 1
var[1] = 13616
var[2] = None
var[3] = "My string, that can have comma"
var[4] = 170.90
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why is your database function returning a string? What you are asking for is possible, but you should fix the source of this problem instead of hacking a solution to it

Comment: Yes...Was exacly this the problem... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard library `csv` readers:

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = u'(1,13616,,"My string, that can have comma",170.90)'
>>> [var] = csv.reader([s[1:-1]])
>>> var[3]
'My string, that can have comma'
```

Some caveats:

- `var[2]` will be an empty string, not `None`, but you can post-process that.
- numbers will be strings and also need post-processing, since csv does not tell the difference between `0` and `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the following:

```
b = []
for i in a:
    if i != None:
        b.append(i)
    if i == None:
        b.append(None)

print (type(b))
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not with the comma.

this works fine:

```
a = (1,13616,"My string, that can have comma",170.90)
```

and this also works:

```
a = (1,13616,None,"My string, that can have comma",170.90)
```

but when you leave two commas ",," it doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Unicode strings are (basically) just strings in Python2 (in Python3, remove the word "basically" in that last sentence). They're written as literals by prefixing a `u` before the string (compare raw-strings `r"something"`, or Py3.4+ formatter strings `f"{some_var}thing"`)

Just strip off your parens and split by comma. You'll have to do some post-parsing if you want `170.90` instead of `u'170.90'` or `None` instead of `u''`, but I'll leave that for you to decide.

```
>>> var.strip(u'()').split(u',')
[u'1', u'13616', u'', u'"My string', u' that can have comma"', u'170.90']
```